# How can I embed a vuejs app inside another vuejs app

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I made an intranet using vuejs. First was something simple, but now I have trouble making maintenance and improvements. So, I split the apps inside the intranet into a separated group of apps, and I solved the communication between them using iframes.

I was wondering if there is a way to call or use the compiled vue apps from a main app. it should be noted that those apps have profile restriction according to the user.

Thanks for the orientation and the ideas.

Iframes, but it work partially nice.

Comment: See the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/application#multiple-application-instances) on multiple app instances. All you have to do is call `createApp` for each instance and mount them to different elements in the parent HTML file.  iframes not required.

Comment: mounted as into a usual page into some DIV in a vue app

Comment: @yoduh ¿Do you have an example of that? As far as I can see, createApp only works with vue files, not already compiled (.js) apps.

Comment: vue file not required.  there are examples in the documentation, e.g. [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/application.html#in-dom-root-component-template) and [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#using-the-global-build)

Comment: Thanks, @yoduh, but I'm afraid that the docs doesn't answer to my question. 

In the case of Vue compiled apps, they return 2 js files. Which one of them should I link on the <script> part?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood.  My suggestion is to not use compiled apps. AFAIK there is not going to be a way to code a main app to reference/communicate with already compiled apps, they all need to be bundled together before compilation, which is my actual suggestion (having multiple createApps).  Though depending on the child apps, and how they're meant to be consumed by the main app there might be the option to [package](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-private-packages) them for import/install.